# How to find the missing equations in Dymola?

Tags: modelica, dymola

I build a model in dymola, but when translating the model, there is an error showing that the system lacks one equation. So, How could I find the missing equations in Dymola?

[image]

Comment: You can narrow it down a bit by checking each model separately. I also recommend this publication: https://modelica.org/events/modelica2008/Proceedings/sessions/session1a3.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dymola already tells you where it assumes that the problem is located.
Apparently the component `stodolaTurbine` is erroneous. And from the info messages you have marked, we can conclude, that there is one equation missing involving real variables.

So go to that component and check if you have one equation for every real variable and that every real variable is used at least in one equation.

Here are some general hints for such problems:

- Read all the errors, warnings and info messages carefully
- Expand all messages to see what Dymola found out
- The info messages can be very helpful, do not forget to check them
  (like *Attempting to further localize singularity* in your screenshot)
- Do that also for all classes which you have instantiated in your example.